# Angular 2 array is adding property to all elements when editing only one

Tags: angular, typescript

Like in title I am trying to edit one element which index I have, and when I did that all elements are edited. I add some element to list which is property of my model, but that element is added to all elemenets lists insteadof only to this one.

```
 unitsViewModel: Array<UnitViewModel> = [];
 mapUnitToViewModel(unit: Unit, serverId: number) {
    var index = this.checkIfUnitExist(unit.code);
    if (index) {
        //here I am adding component to componenets list(property of unitViewModelwhh)
        this.unitsViewModel[index].component.push({
            componentId: unit.id,
            serverId: serverId
        });
    }
    else {
        this.componenetArray.length = 0;
        this.componenetArray.push({
            componentId: unit.id,
            serverId: serverId
        });

        this.unitsViewModel.push(
            {
                id: ++this.idIndex,
                component: this.componenetArray,
                label: unit.code
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understand well , u have the problem just when the Unit Exists ( where the index is found )  ?

Comment: How does your html template look like? How are you displaying your units in your html?

Comment: I am not displaying it, I use them to make same call to api.

Comment: Can you output here `this.unitsViewModel` and  `index`?

Comment: I resolve that, the this.componenetArray, which i use to create new object, in every singl object contain the same reference beacuse its the same array, and then when I push to that in differents objects it still push to the same array which every single object contain.